# pip installing ibm_watson_machine_learning module fails

Tags: python, pip, ibm-watson

I'm pip installing the ibm_watson_machine_learning module on a new virtual environment running python 3.12.1. I get an error saying 'could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects'.

For some background, I did this on a clean, new virtual environment with

```
py -m venv venv
.\venv\scripts\activate
```

I also tried pip installing pandas like so,

```
pip install pandas
```

before trying to do

```
pip install ibm_watson_machine_learning
```

but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing Microsoft C++ Build Tools. I got it [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

```bash
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install pandas
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this did not work for me. What worked for me is installing  C++ Build Tools.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new environment for these new installation because its dependencies issue
python -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate  # On Unix/Linux
myenv\Scripts\activate     # On Windows